# How can I make emacs interpret tilde ~ as a literal tilde (never to modify letters like Ã, Ñ)

Tags: key-bindings

I want to always have tilde insert a literal tilde (~). How can I ensure this in emacs?

This also happens when I start emacs with `-q` or `-Q`!

Version info:

```
GNU Emacs 27.1
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GNU Emacs comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You may redistribute copies of GNU Emacs
under the terms of the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING.
```

Comment: It works for me. Are you using a special keyboard map for the whole (x)windows session? Are you using a `global-map` in emacs?

Comment: If you write ~ and then N, do you get Ñ or ~N?

Comment: `~N`, but I use the standard keyboard layout for Xwin, and only turn on a different `global-map` in Emacs when I need one.

Comment: I will look up what a global-map is. Thanks

Comment: It may also depend on the input method you use (if you use one): `M-x describe-input-method`. You might also want to try starting emacs without any init file: `emacs -Q` or `emacs -q` (they ignore different init files - readd the manpage of emacs); depending on the outcome you should have a better idea of who turns on the tilde composing.

Comment: You can see what function the key is bound to with `^Hk~`, and configure/adjust that function.